# assigning recordsource to subreport in ms access

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, vba, report

I have a report which in turn has two subreports inside it.The record source of the main report is changes according to a condition. To do that i included the if condition in the onclick of the button that leads to the report and if true i have used this code to open the report
    DoCmd.OpenReport "rptPMLOGSHEET", acViewPreview, , LinkCriTeRia, , "Query1_filter"

Then in the Open event of the main report i have included the following code:

```
If Len(Me.OpenArgs & "") > 0 Then
    Me.RecordSource = Me.OpenArgs
End If
```

This works perfectly.Now the recordsource of the subreport depends on a condition too...In the report open of the subreport i passed the recordsource directly

If condition=true
Me.recordsource="Query name"

This opens up the report fine but as soon as i click on the arrow to go to the second page is gives me an error that says 'Runtime error 2191-you cant set a recordsource property in print preview or after printing has started' and the debugger leads

```
Me.recordsource="Query name"
```

Is there any way i can retain the printpreview functionality and at the same time also get the report to run?
I tried putting the code in report load event but the report does not give correct results.
Any alternative approach is also welcome.
Appreciate the help

Answer (score 1):

Move the code line to the main report:

```
If condition = True Then
    Me!YourSubreportControlName.Report.RecordSource = "Query name"
End If
```